# Visual Studio Code - Ctrl + . add usings inside namespaces

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working with a convention of putting using statements inside namespaces:

```
namespace ShoppingCart.Modules
{
  using Nancy;
  using Nancy.ModelBinding;

  public CartModule : NancyModule
  ...
```

However, Ctrl + . defaults to adding them outside (unless there is already a using statement inside the namespace).

How can I configure VS Code so that it always defaults to adding the using statement inside the namespace and I don't have to move at least the first one manually?